# Pasta in San Francisco!

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, california, recommendations, san-francisco

Is there any good place for pasta in San Francisco? I tried 2-3 restaurants, but wasn't really satisfy..

I am Greek, which might make it harder to get satisfied, but I don't know the city, so a local/American may be able to suggest something! :)

Clarification: Best in terms of food quality.

Comment: There are obviously hundreds of places to get pasta in SF. What do you mean by good? Good according to who?

Comment: To the poster @Fiksdal. You see, I understand that personal opinion matters here, but for example [when I was in Barcelona](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/travel/#Spain), I asked an old couple, and they suggested 7 portes. If you have been there, you would know what I mean. ;)

Comment: I hope you were satisfied with the answer you got from Zach Lipton.

Comment: Yes @Fiksdal I was! I haven't visited these place yet though, but I am pretty sure this answer is helpful! :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what matters. Next time you ask a question, consider narrowing it down to clear criteria and avoid subjective requests, that way it can avoid getting closed :)

Comment: @Fiksdal Good according to me! Obviously ;)

Comment: @ZachLipton Cool. My next question is gonna be "What's Zach Lipton's favourite pasta restaurant in LA?"

Comment: @Fiksdal I updated my question with the clarification. Now it will be OK, thank you for the comments.

Comment: It's simple math @pnuts (if you think about it, like a philosopher :P ), but thanks for the comment, edited. But anyway, the question is closed, so please don't produce more noise than the one we have already produced! ;) And just to be fair, Zach's answer is awesome.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts for the tip! :) I will try to have it in mind...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am personally a huge fan of [Delfina Restaurant](http://delfinasf.com/restaurant/) on 18th near Dolores Park. They do a simple spaghetti that's always just perfectly cooked and delicious, along with a few other changing pasta dishes (but the spaghetti is great!). Reservations are recommended, but if you show up early and sit at the counter, that can work too. Don't get it confused with the Pizzeria Delfina next door, though they offer good pizza as well.

There are many choices, but some other options with well-regarded housemade fresh pasta include [Flower+Water](http://www.flourandwater.com/) (which has pastas a la carte and a $75/person pasta tasting menu, they're serious about their pasta), [A16](https://www.yelp.com/biz/a16-san-francisco-4) (I haven't been there in a while though), [Cotonga](https://www.yelp.com/biz/cotogna-san-francisco) (or, for a really fancy meal, Quince next door), [Locanda](http://www.locandasf.com/) (Delfina's sister restaurant, which does more Roman food), [Perbacco](http://www.perbaccosf.com/), and [SPQR](http://spqrsf.com/). For a much simpler and casual vibe, consider [Emmy's Spaghetti Shack](https://www.zagat.com/r/emmys-spaghetti-shack-san-francisco).

Some other lists you might want to consult: [10 of the Best Places to Eat Pasta in San Francisco](http://www.7x7.com/10-of-the-best-places-to-eat-pasta-in-san-francisco-1786251820.html), [10 Must-Try Pasta Dishes in San Francisco](https://www.zagat.com/b/san-francisco/10-must-try-pasta-dishes-in-san-francisco).

Note also that Mac and Cheese is having a bit of a moment in the Bay Area as well. I consider that type of pasta a separate category from the fine Italian homemade pastas above, equally worthy yet clearly distinct, but you could see this article on [Where to Get the 12 Best Mac & Cheese Dishes in SF Right Now](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/san-francisco/giant-slip-n-slide-coming-to-sf-slide-the-city), along with restaurants specializing in the dish such as [MacDaddy](http://www.macdaddysf.com/) in Potrero Hill and [Homeroom](http://homeroom510.com/) in Oakland.

Comment: Argh, I couldn't wait until 5, so I went to Cotonga (which was open around 2.30, the time I came in the restaurant, on Saturdays), and daaaamn, **Reservations are strongly recommended**! I had to eat at the bar! :P Not impressed though, but better than all the other pastas I have tried in SF so far, so thank you Zach, you are a belly-saver! :) The restaurant is placed near [Peter+Paul's church](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76662/what-is-san-franciscos-most-famous-church), which lies in such a lovely neighbor, reminds me of home, in a way. High grounds, flowers, nice houses, sun!!!